# How to handle vacation being cut short?

Tags: united-states, manager, time-off

A bit of context first. I report to the Owner and CEO (not actual titles, the structure is complicated but this is the simplest way to describe them) of the company but my schedule for my regular non-project work is made by the GM of my home location. The company works in the recreation industry, and I am a manager in addition to my other roles which means all my time-off requests go through the CEO instead of the GM.

Recently (this week, as of the posting of this question) I was supposed to be on a week-long vacation. I submitted and got approved for time off for every date I needed this year last November. However, the GM scheduled me for my regular Sunday and Saturday hours despite it being part of my time-off request approved 9 months prior. Frankly, this and concessions to my volunteer summer teaching gig causing me to miss all of this vacation except for ~1/20th of the week has irritated me. The Sunday I managed to get covered by the other manager, but the Saturday I was unable to get covered.

This and other issues has essentially brought me to my wit’s end and this job I used to enjoy has become a huge stress in my life.

The way I see it, I have four possible choices of how to handle with this that don’t involve not taking action:

**1. Resign.** Quite literally a path of least resistance in that I’ll be removing the main source of all my stress lately.

**2. Request to be transferred to another location.** While all the other locations are more than four times the commute to get to, I already have established relations with all their GMs and know I’ll get along with them.

**3. Inform the CEO of the situation.** I’m hesitant to do this because it may lead to the immediate termination of the GM which would cause significant disarray because I’m the only on-location manager capable of covering for the GM fully but I’m not available for the next two weeks.

**4. Do nothing until my next time-off that was approved in the same “batch.”** If the GM pulls the same stunt again I can simply not show up (which would be justified due to the time-off being documented) which may have the same effect as #3 but will be at a much better time to deal with any sudden firings.

*Edit: this is the 7th or so instance of approved time-off being ignored.*

*Edit 2: I made concessions with my teaching position 8 months ago knowing my time-off had been approved, arranging it so I would get 3 out of 7 of the days to spend on vacation with family I rarely see. The ignored time-off cut that to 1 day (effectively 6 hours due to the family being majority Latter-Day Saints and that day being a Sunday) due to travel requirements.*

Comment: If he sacks the GM, woukd you offer to come in as replacement? If not then don’t... Unless he offers significant remuneration...

Comment: Consider it a tip of the iceberg. It’s still time lost that I could’ve spent with my dying grandmother.

Comment: Could you add a country location to the Question please?

Answer (score 5):

> How to handle vacation being cut short?

You wrote "this and concessions to my volunteer summer teaching gig causing me to miss all of this vacation". So if "this" accounts for one day, and "concessions" accounts for all the rest, then no matter what you do in regard to this job, you are only getting one day back at best.

If I saw that I was incorrectly scheduled, I'd bring it up with the GM immediately and indicate that I won't be around due to my vacation. Obviously your summer teaching gig is a completely separate issue.

But it sounds like the real problem here is that you aren't pleased with the GM. If this is the same GM that caused you grief in your prior question, then perhaps it's best if you find a new job.

Find a new job. Make sure you ask enough questions to feel confident that the new job won't have the same issues as the old one. Get and formally accept an offer. Give your notice. Work out your notice period. Leave this job and start your new job.

Comment: +1 Unclear if that is the whole situation, but with the present wording of the question, there is indeed no evidence that in the recent incident the GM cost the asker more than the one scheduled day they were unable to get someone else to cover - **what happened to the rest of the week is a mystery**.  It may be that this isn't the reality of the situation and the rest was somehow clawed back too, but we can only go by what ends up in the question actually posted which seems to be more a summary of overwhelming feelings than a clear statement of the details leading to them.

Comment: Well, those would be a result of their own decision to take that gig, they can't really blame the company or the GM for that, yet they seem to be blaming them for the overall result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is the 7th time this has happened. Without being harsh, this is something that you should have complained about every time it has happened.

For all the business knows, you could have made non-cancellable bookings, either for flights or accommodation.

First of all, assume it is a mistake by the GM and bring this oversight to their attention. Give them a chance to fix it. Don't get into the trap of justifying why you are inflexible. Your personal life is your business. You booked the leave well in advance because you needed to make arrangements. Leave it at that. Do this as soon as possible.

If they are unwilling to rectify the situation, you do need to bring it to your CEO's attention. Explain the same. If your CEO is not sympathetic, then you probably have a new set of information to consider what to do, and at least you know where you stand with the CEO. If your CEO fires the GM for not respecting your leave request, and then rosters you on during your leave, don't you find that a bit hypocritical?

I would never simply just not rock up to work. You really can't pretend you were unaware.

Comment: You can only raise so much hell before you get tired of living in it. The first 5 times I was very clear about how big of an issue it was and I was given bonuses for working those. However this time the GM left on vacation immediately after sending the schedule and it was sent a week prior as apposed to the proper two weeks prior.